# Display specific rows and update in GridView using Linq database c#

Tags: c#, linq, gridview

I am new in C# and I want to display specific rows in GridView. I could do this but I could not update it.
My code:

```
 private void bindGridView()
    {
        myContextDataContext context = new myContextDataContext();
        var q2 = from p in context.employees
                 where p.check_is_mngr == 1
                 select p;
        employeeDataGridView.DataSource = q2;
    }
```

I called bindgridview() in bossAcc_Load function.In my form,I have add_new button and save button.
This is save button function:

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Validate();
        this.employeeBindingSource.EndEdit();
        this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.my_proDataSet);   

    }
```

But when I click save button,didn't update data.What should I do?

Comment: What is your project? Winforms?

Comment: yes.in c# i add winforms @asdnafn

Comment: what do UpdateAll and endEdit methods  do? update data  in database?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
var q2 = from p in context.employees
                 where p.check_is_mngr == 1
                 select p;
employeeDataGridView.DataSource = null;
employeeDataGridView.DataSource = q2 ;
```